# Error NU1102: Unable to find package runtime.osx-arm64.Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler with version (= 7.0.4)

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, macos-monterey

I'm getting the below error when trying to build a solution for the first time on my Mac (with an M1 chip).

```
Error NU1102: Unable to find package runtime.osx-arm64.Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler with version (= 7.0.4)
  - Found 2 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 8.0.0-preview.1.23110.8 ] (NU1102) (CharityAdmin.Api)
```

The problem being that when looking at the versions for this nuget package here -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.osx-arm64.Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler/ it seems that there isn't a version for 7.0.4? And only for the .NET 8 preview. I'd love to change the target framework to .NET 8 however reading up on here -> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-preview-2/ it seems like Visual Studio for Mac support isn't yet available. Do I have much options here? Or is it that I'm missing an sdk? Or perhaps I can't use visual studio for mac and have to rely on the CLI?

I have installed both .NET 8 preview and .NET 7 sdks. Rebuilt the solution using Visual Studio for Mac, and still got the error.